# Racket: `syntax-local-introduce` across module boundary

Tags: macros, racket

In the file below, the macro `m2` defines an identifier `foo`, and makes it available to the user code via `syntax-local-introduce`. When subsequently expanding `m1`, `(free-identifier=? #'m2-id #'user-id)` evaluates to `#t` as expected.

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax (m1 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ m2-id user-id)
     #`#,(free-identifier=? #'m2-id #'user-id)]))

(define-syntax (m2 stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ user-id)
     #`(begin (define (foo) 1)
              (m1 foo #,(syntax-local-introduce #'user-id)))]))

(m2 foo) ;; => #t
(m2 foo) ;; => #t
```

However, if I wrap the two macros in a module, `(free-identifier=? #'m2-id #'user-id)` evaluates to `#f`.

```
#lang racket

(module m racket
  (define-syntax (m1 stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ m2-id user-id)
       #`#,(free-identifier=? #'m2-id #'user-id)]))

  (define-syntax (m2 stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ user-id)
       #`(begin (define (foo) 1)
                (m1 foo #,(syntax-local-introduce #'user-id)))]))

  (provide m2))

(require 'm)

(m2 foo) ;; => #f
(m2 foo) ;; => #f
```

Why is this happening?

How can I solve this and obtain the first example's behaviour when the macros are defined in a separate module?

Please note that I want to be able to execute the macro more than once, so using `(define (#,(datum->syntax stx 'foo)) 1)` is not an option, as this would result in conflicting definitions when the macro is called twice.

I tried using `((make-syntax-delta-introducer #'foo #'user-id) #'user-id)` instead of `#,(syntax-local-introduce #'user-id)`, but it doesn't work either.

### Actual code where I'm using this

Here is (in pseudocode) the actual code I'm writing:

```
(define-syntax (define* stx)
  ... expand types, uses free-identifier=? ...)

(define-syntax (define-function-group stx)
    (syntax-parse stx
      [(_ ((~literal defun) (f-name arg ...) ret-type body) ...)
       #`(begin (define-type-expander (return-type-of stx)
                  (syntax-parse stx
                    [(_ (~literal f-name)) #'ret-type] ...))
                (define* (f-name arg ...) : ret-type
                  body) ...)]))

;; defines a type expander "return-type-of"
(define-function-group
  (defun (f1) (Listof String) '("a" "b"))
  (defun (f2 [a : (return-type-of f1)] (length '("a" "b")))))

;; defines another type expander "return-type-of"
(define-function-group etc.)
```

Where `define-type-expander` is from my type-expander library and works like match-expanders (I should package it at some point, but it still needs some work). `define*` (which corresponds to `m1` above) is a variant of `define*` that expands types, and it uses `free-identifier=?` at some point to find the right type-expander definition. `define-function-group` (which corresponds fo `m2` above) allows referring to the return type of another function, using `(return-type-of some-function-name)`. The thing is that each call to `define-function-group` introduces a new copy of `return-type-of`, so it needs to have the macro's scope to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I admit, I’m pretty baffled as to what this is trying to solve. You want a passed in identifier to be `free-identifier=?` to another, unrelated identifier? I don’t get what the purpose of this code is, and I smell a potential [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188673).

Comment: @AlexisKing I added the pseudocode for my real use case. I know `syntax-parameterize` would be a good solution here, but it causes other problems (I vaguely suspect some quirk in my type-expander library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more hygienic way of doing it, but this is what I came up with:

You say that `datum->syntax` isn't an option, but consider the following:

```
(define-syntax (m2 stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ user-id)
       (with-syntax ([foo (syntax-local-introduce (datum->syntax stx 'foo))])
       #`(begin (define (foo) 1)
                (m1 foo #,(syntax-local-introduce #'user-id))))]))
```

While this uses `datum->syntax`, it also adds the use-site scopes to `foo`, making the identifier unique to each macro expansion. If you replace `m2` with the above in your example code, everything runs as desired (and, as you predict, removing `syntax-local-introduce` causes duplicate definition errors).